# Notify Blazor + EF Core server when a db table is externallly changed?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, onchange, database-table

I have a EF Core + Blazor client/server application where a table in an sql database may be updated by an external service. The server keeps a copy of that table and should react to changes to the original table (the application needs a copy for reasons). The external service may add, delete or modify records or even write the entire table from scratch, dropping the old table in the process.

Is there a way to have the server be notified whenever that external table is changed, similar to a DB trigger? Or is there a way to have a DB trigger notify the server so that I can process the notification in code in the server?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)

Comment: MS SQL Server, but my question is not limited to that.

Comment: I don't think there can be a universal solution. Each DBMS will have its own solution.